# Почему не удаётся закрыть программу при использовании pystray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, tkinter

Написал программу с `tkinter`, которая при закрытии окна обязана сворачиваться в трей. Но при попытке выхода из программы, путём нажатия кнопки "Закрыть" в трее, которая выполняет функцию:

```
def quit_window(icon, item):
    icon.stop() # Удаление иконки из трея
    sys.exit(0) # Завершение программы
```

Но оно не работает, т.к. выдаёт ошибку:

```
An error occurred when calling message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a-par\mini_library_2020\env\lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 386, in _dispatcher
    return int(icon._message_handlers.get(
  File "C:\Users\a-par\mini_library_2020\env\lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 207, in _on_notify 
    descriptors[index - 1](self)
  File "C:\Users\a-par\mini_library_2020\env\lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 267, in inner
    callback(self)
  File "C:\Users\a-par\mini_library_2020\env\lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 368, in __call__
    return self._action(icon, self)
  File "c:/Users/a-par/mini_library_2020/LC.pyw", line 2976, in quit_window
    sys.exit(0)
SystemExit: 0
```

Также, в программе есть бот для ВК, который работает в свёрнутом режиме(для того и нужно свёртывание в трей). Этот бот работает в отдельном потоке от GUI. Я пробовал полностью удалить бота, но это не помогает. Мало ли проблема в потоках, но я так не думаю...

Вот [видео](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16XOulAT_588u_aK4iVvTzoRV_lsPCh06/view?usp=sharing) с этой проблемой

Вот минимально воспроизводимый код:

```
import pystray
import sys
import time
from PIL import Image
from pystray import Menu, MenuItem


def exit_action(icon):
    sys.exit(0)


def setup(icon):
    icon.visible = True
    
    i = 0
    while icon.visible:
        # Some payload code
        print(i)
        i += 1
        
        time.sleep(5)


def init_icon():
    icon = pystray.Icon('mon')
    icon.menu = Menu(
        MenuItem('Exit', lambda : exit_action(icon)),
    )
    icon.icon = Image.open('C:/Users/a-par/mini_library_2020/logo.ico')
    icon.title = 'tooltip'

def vk_bot_start(self):
    file = open(os.path.dirname(
        os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/vk_api.txt", 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    if lines != []:
        if network() == True:
            threading.Thread(target=vk_bot, args=[
                lines[0][:-1], lines[1], self]).start()


def vk_bot(token, id_g, self):
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token, api_version='5.122')

    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, id_g)

    vk = vk_session.get_api()

    del_ac = 0

    keyboard_help = VkKeyboard(inline=False)
    # тут идёт описание клавиатуры бота
    #А это сама прослушка ЛС сообщества. Далее идёт много условий и текста бота
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

    icon.run(setup)

init_icon()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    threading.Thread(target=vk_bot_start, args=[app, ]).start() # Вот запуск бота
    app.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', withdraw_window) # Эта строка нужна, чтобы программа при нажатии на крестик сворачивалась в трей
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Нужно добавить минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @insolor, ох... Совсем забыл...

Comment: Давно не появлялся на ruSO XD

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть вот это issue: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray/issues/17 . Вообще, есть подозрение, что pystray ловит внутри себя BaseException, поэтому через `sys.exit(0)` прервать выполнение не получится. Только останавливать цикл обработки событий, как в [примере](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray/issues/17#issuecomment-322420173).

Comment: @insolor, это всё здорово и хорошо, но вот только программа то не завершается... Она продолжает висеть между двумя "мирами" и грузит ПК

Comment: Без кода ничего нельзя сказать.

Comment: @insolor, знаю, потому строчу минимально рабочий код.

Comment: @insolor, код добавил прям из вашего совета. Всё равно не пашет как надо

Comment: В моем совете завершение идет через изменение поля icon.visible, без вызова `sys.exit(0)` вообще. Сравните код  функции exit_action в вашем вопросе и по [ссылке](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray/issues/17#issuecomment-322420173).

Comment: @insolor, но дело в том, что у меня продолжает в другом потоке работать бот ВК, потому надо как-то его остановить! Потому я снова и пробовал через `sys.exit(0)`

Comment: Где этот поток в примере в вопросе?)

Comment: @insolor, да блин XD ИЗвиняюсь, за всем невозможно уследить)

Comment: 1 - Этот комментарий в коде ничего не прояснил. 2 - Есть способы прибить поток без sys.exit

Comment: В общем, нужно править сам pystray, чтобы исключение SystemExit обрабатывалось нормально, а не просто логировалось.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо большое. Будем искать как его переписать -_-

Comment: Ну, у меня вроде бы заработало, посмотрю, может получится сделать pull реквест. Все-таки добавьте в вопрос, как вы запускаете бота - через threading или еще как-то, чтобы я у себя мог проверить, что все работает как надо.

Comment: @insolor, к сожалению, сейчас не могу, т.к. не у ПК. Как будет возможность - добавлю примерный код бота

Comment: @insolor, добавил я чуток кода для бота

Comment: @insolor, вышло что-нибудь или до сих пор не пашет?